Programmatically applied constraints are not working in ViewController
As I'm integrating a native iOS screen in a Flutter plugin I have to set constraints programmatically for the ui as there is no storyboard.
I have these UI components:
    var overlayMaskView: UIView = UIView()
    var previewView: UIView = UIView()
    var stillImagePreviewView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var viewFinderShapeLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var viewfinderShapeType: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
    var vehicleTypeLabel: UILabel  = UILabel()
    var vehicleType: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()

I'm reading their constraints from the storyboard but I'm struggling to replicate them programmatically.
I was able to set constraints for overlayMaskView, previewView and stillImagePreviewView four anchors to the safe area anchors.
//        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black//.black
        previewView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        previewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        previewView.isOpaque = true
        previewView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        previewView.clipsToBounds = false
        previewView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        previewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


        stillImagePreviewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stillImagePreviewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        stillImagePreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        stillImagePreviewView.isOpaque = true
        stillImagePreviewView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        stillImagePreviewView.clipsToBounds = true
        stillImagePreviewView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view.addSubview(stillImagePreviewView)
        stillImagePreviewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stillImagePreviewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stillImagePreviewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stillImagePreviewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        overlayMaskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        overlayMaskView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        overlayMaskView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        overlayMaskView.isOpaque = true
        overlayMaskView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        overlayMaskView.clipsToBounds = false
        overlayMaskView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view.addSubview(overlayMaskView)
        overlayMaskView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        overlayMaskView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        overlayMaskView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        overlayMaskView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

Then the first label viewFinderShapeLabel which has center x aligned to the view x axis, a top anchor to the safe area top anchor with a constant of 8, leading and trailing anchors to the safe area leading and trailing anchors with a constant of 16.
So i set them all like so and it's at desired position :
        viewFinderShapeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewFinderShapeLabel.text = "Formato targa"
        viewFinderShapeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        viewFinderShapeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        viewFinderShapeLabel.isEnabled = true
        viewFinderShapeLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        viewFinderShapeLabel.isOpaque = false
        viewFinderShapeLabel.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        viewFinderShapeLabel.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view.addSubview(viewFinderShapeLabel)
        viewFinderShapeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewFinderShapeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        viewFinderShapeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        viewFinderShapeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

Then there is the first segmented controller which also has center x aligned to the view x axis, leading and trailing anchors to the safe area leading and trailing anchors with a constant of 16, but its  top anchor to the viewFinderShapeLabel's bottom anchor with a constant of 8.
        viewfinderShapeType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewfinderShapeType = UISegmentedControl(items: ["RETTANGOLARE", "QUADRATA"])
        viewfinderShapeType.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 0)
        viewfinderShapeType.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
        viewfinderShapeType.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        viewfinderShapeType.isEnabled = true
        viewfinderShapeType.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewfinderShapeType.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        viewfinderShapeType.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view.addSubview(viewfinderShapeType)
        viewfinderShapeType.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewfinderShapeType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        viewfinderShapeType.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        viewfinderShapeType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewFinderShapeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

This setup fails as the segmented control is placed at the top left corner without any spacing.
What am I doing wrong causing these latest constraints not to work?

It doesn't make sense to set both the leading/trailing anchors and the centerx anchor. Either set the  center and the width or set the leading/trailing anchors

Hi, @Paulw11 long time since I asked a Swift related question.
Indeed using the three constraints is redundant, i know, in fact I will only use the trailing and leading ones.

@Fabio I was about asking you about your answer but it has been deleted??

You have created a segmented control as a property of your class:
var viewfinderShapeType: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()

The reason your code puts the segmented control at top left is due to these two lines:
viewfinderShapeType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewfinderShapeType = UISegmentedControl(items: ["RETTANGOLARE", "QUADRATA"])

The first line sets .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false on the control which is a property of your class.
The second line creates a NEW UISegmentedControl ... which does not have .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false ... and assigns that new control to the class property.
You could either swap the order of those two lines (create the new instance and then set translates...), or,
declare your control like this:
var viewfinderShapeType: UISegmentedControl = {
    let v = UISegmentedControl(items: ["RETTANGOLARE", "QUADRATA"])
    return v
}()

and get rid of this line:
//viewfinderShapeType = UISegmentedControl(items: ["RETTANGOLARE", "QUADRATA"])


that's it! that's te reason why..
is it safe to assume that .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false should be set as last ?

@Vincenzo - By default, when you create a UI object it is set to true. So, it just needs to be set on the instance / object after it has been created.

sure, I couldn't see that I was creating a new segmented control instead of just assign items to the empty one created in the ViewController properties.
It was fine for the label set as the first thing, but not for the segmented control as I was in fact creating a new one and assign it to the ViewController property
I was going in circles. thanks again

I don't quite understand how you want to create the UI... Below is an example based on your code that could help you, the part that changes color is already an imageView:
import UIKit

var overlayMaskView = UIView()
var previewView = UIView()
var stillImagePreviewView = UIImageView()
var viewFinderShapeLabel = UILabel()
var viewfinderShapeType = UISegmentedControl()
var vehicleTypeLabel = UILabel()
var vehicleType = UISegmentedControl()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

view.backgroundColor = .black

previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
previewView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //.black
view.addSubview(previewView)
previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
previewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

viewFinderShapeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewFinderShapeLabel.text = "Formato targa"
viewFinderShapeLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
viewFinderShapeLabel.textAlignment = .center
viewFinderShapeLabel.textColor = .white
previewView.addSubview(viewFinderShapeLabel)
viewFinderShapeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
viewFinderShapeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
viewFinderShapeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
viewFinderShapeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

let items = ["RETTANGOLARE", "QUADRATA"]
viewfinderShapeType = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
viewfinderShapeType.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
viewfinderShapeType.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
viewfinderShapeType.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
viewfinderShapeType.addTarget(self, action: #selector(change), for: .valueChanged)
viewfinderShapeType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

previewView.addSubview(viewfinderShapeType)
viewfinderShapeType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewFinderShapeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
viewfinderShapeType.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

stillImagePreviewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stillImagePreviewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
stillImagePreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
stillImagePreviewView.backgroundColor = .white
view.addSubview(stillImagePreviewView)
stillImagePreviewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
stillImagePreviewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
stillImagePreviewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewfinderShapeType.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
stillImagePreviewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

@objc fileprivate func change() {
if stillImagePreviewView.backgroundColor == .white {
    stillImagePreviewView.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
} else {
    stillImagePreviewView.backgroundColor = .white
  }
 }
}



Nice, thanks!
I'm looking into it to see why my version isn't working..as also in your version the top anchor for the  segmented control is bond to the label bottom anchor.
I tried your settings in my view controller and they do work.. still something in my setting breaks it and the segmented control ends up in the top left corner..
I'm surely setting some parameters wrong

@Vincenzo where would you like to tie it? Side by side? Explain better, so I can solve it for you... Maybe add a drawing

it's exactly like you've done. just I was setting .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for the segmented control, and then declaring a new one .  see DonMag answer.
Thank you for your answer and help

In fact in your code viewfinderShapeType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false is the last line of settings for viewfinderShapeType
